# Scanning using Epson XP 530

Tags: drivers, scanner

I have an Epson XP-530 and I cannot get it to scan in Ubuntu. Are there any drivers I need to install for this printer to enable scanning?

Answer (score 0):

There are drivers from Epson [at this location](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php?version=1.3.20), supporting Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 16.10 and 17.04

To be honest, this was not difficult to find with a simple "epxon xp 530 linux" search on google